# rails_admin - embedded, namespaced models not showing

Tags: mongoid, rails-admin

Having a bit of trouble over here.

In the following example, Offer::PropertyInfo does not show up in the rails_admin dashboard:

```
class Offer
  include GlobalID::Identification
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :price, type: Integer
  field :funding_source, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  field :phone, type: String
  field :phone_verified, type: Mongoid::Boolean, default: false

  embeds_one :property_info, class_name: "Offer::PropertyInfo"

  belongs_to :property
end

class Offer::PropertyInfo
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :street_name, type: String
  field :street_number, type: String
  field :unit_number, type: String
  field :city, type: String
  field :state, type: String
  field :zip, type: String

  embedded_in :offer
end
```

[image: Not linked in the admin]

Any ideas why not? Is it because these are in the same file? Namespaced? Using mongoid 4.0.1.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any  workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating `def name street_name end` in PropertyInfo class?  That should display in RA.